# ffmpeg: problems when copying the audio

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg

When I run this `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -codec copy video.avi` I get a broken audio: a crackling like a stuck LP. The input-audio is `aac`

When I re-encode the audio like this `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -codec:v:0 copy video.avi` the audio in the out-file works.

What could be the reason for the problems, when copying the audio?

Comment: ffmpeg is a bit counter-intuitive with it's args. I think that you should have the `-codec copy`  before the `-i` ... in general, parameters relating to a file must appear before the `-i file`, but does it mean *copy from* or *copy to*... `-codec copy` should apply to both streams, but if it doesn't work by moving the args, try encoding options for each stream `-acodec copy -vcodec copy`, or just `-acodec copy` on its own and see if that works... Mabe there is something wrong with that particular stream(?)... Try it on another similar video and see if you get the same issue recurring ...

Comment: Copying only the audio works: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -acodec copy sound.aac`

Comment: Have you tried `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -acodec copy -vcodec copy video.avi`, as @Peter.O suggested?

Comment: AAC and AVI don't mix well -- it's a unsupported combination